# Creating MILP Model in CPLEX automatically

Tags: c++, optimization, modeling, cplex

I am trying to set up an MILP Problem in CPLEX. The model is created out of an input in the form of a "System Configuration" file and has to be created automatically within CPLEX since ten thousands of constraints and thousands of decision variables has to be created.

I had several ideas in mind: 
1) Define the constraints as matrix/vector constraints in the form A*x = b by defining the corresponding matrix and vectors from the input. But I could not find any opportunity to do this in CPLEX.

2) I found out there is a possibility to build up linear constraints with  *IloLinearNumExpr* but this is only possible in JAVA? I could not find the class anywhere in the C++ Interface.

3) At last, it is also possible to write the model in an LP file automatically and import it. Would you rather recommend this procedure since it is platform Independent and offers a better readable model instead of the exported model from CPLEX which uses x as the only variable name?

Best regards,
Binh

Comment: As suggested, using one of the CPLEX APIs is probably the way to go.  See the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/homepages/CPLEX.html).  While the LP file format is really nice for debugging (and getting a human readable representation of a model) it is not ideal in production, as you can loose precision when storing floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it via the API. There are APIs for lots of languages. In the CPLEX examples folder on my PC there are standard examples in C, C++, C# Java, Python and VB. Just read the appropriate part of the documentation.

Comment: But is there a way to print out the model in a readable way? Using the "cout << model" results in an output of the model composing of ILO variables and not the given names that I gave it in my C++ code. This happens also when I try to export the model. This is kinda frustrating when I try to debug my code.

Comment: Are you actually naming the variables? When I set the variables' names explicitly they come out with those names in e.g. exported LP files. Same is true for constraints that get explicitly named. I think from memory you need to use something like IloNumVar.setName(char* name)

Comment: Thank you! I didnt name the variables. The output looks quite nice after naming the variables.